# How to Store 24-hour military format time to Django Models in TimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to store time in 24-hour format to Django models. I'm using TimeField in models. So far when trying to store time  in standard 12-hour format it works. 
But when trying to store time in 24 hour format it no longer works and instead gives an error saying to give a valid time.

My application stores credits as hours. The user pays for the number of hours they want to consume and pays for it accordingly. I then store the remaining credits they have left in `remaining_session_credits`. When the user registers, the user inputs an integer at a max of 24. This means that the user can only have a max of 24 hours of credits to use. This is why I'm trying to store that 24 integer in a TimeField.

Here's my code so far:

My models

```
session_credits = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
remaining_session_credits = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My views

```
def save_enrollment(request):
try:
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"), parse_float=decimal.Decimal) if request.body.decode("utf-8") else {}
    if data.get("session_credits", None) is not None:
        data["remaining_session_credits"] = timedelta(hours=data.get("session_credits"))

    return success("Success!")
except Exception as e:
    return HttpResponse(str(e), status=400)
```

`data.get("session_credits")` here is an integer which I'm converting to hours. For example `data.get('session_credits') = 24` I want that `24` to be in time format and be saved in TimeField in models.

Comment: Can you please add your code in your question?

Comment: @RodXavier I've now added my code

Comment: You are assigning a `timedelta` object to a `datetime` field.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is the `data` dict coming from? Show us a minimal complete model, view and form if you are using one.

Comment: Thanks @trixn I've added more detail to my code.

Comment: @RodXavier I've changed my models. TimeField only works however with 12-hour standard format.

Comment: `TimeField` supports both formats. But, your `remaining_session_credits` field expects either a string or a `datetime.time` instance instead of a `datetime.timedelta` instance. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS.

Comment: @Mikebarson a timedelta is not a valid time. It's a difference between two points in time, therefore you can't store it in a `TimeField`. Also is seems a litte bit odd that a field that stores a point in time is called "session_credits". Maybe you should describe what your are trying to achieve with this code. See also the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @trixn Thanks. However, how should I change my integer so that I could save it to `TimeField` and should also be saved in 24-hour format?

Comment: I can't answer this because i don't know about the nature of the data you are trying to store there. Can you desribe your application in a broader picture? It doesn't seem right that a value named `session_credits` is a time. Shoudn't this be an integer in the first place? See also [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @trixn Added description about my app.

Comment: @Mikebarson seems like you don't need a `Timefield`. I think either the `IntegerField`, `FloatField` or `DecimalField` would serve your purpose. Or, you can actually use Django's [Duration field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField).

Comment: @RodXavier alright thanks! Btw, can you upvote my post?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as far as i understand you have two options depending on how the user "consumes" credits.

If he "subscribes" for a period of x hours from the time of registering then you could just store the time when his subscription expires. You could calculate this with with time when the user registered + time he bought and store that value in a `DateTime` field. You can then check against the current time if his subscribtion has already expired.

If he actively needs to do something to "consume" credits how do you measure this? This is much harder to implement. Also in this case it would be better to store the value either as an integer (`IntegerField`) or as a `Duration`, depending no how accurate the information has to be stored.

Comment: That makes sense. I want to clarify about `DurationField` I've never used it before and the Django docs doesn't provide much detail on how to use and what to use it for. When should I use `DurationField`?

Comment: @Mikebarson You should use it if you need to store information about a period of time. Something like time needed to do x. How long does Usain Bolt need for 100 meters? 9.5 seconds. That would be a period of time. Different to that a TimeField stores a point in time. Something like: When will the package arrive? At 1 pm. So in your case: How long is the user allowed to use my service? 5 hours, 14 minutes and 3 seconds. This is a period of time, not a point in time. But if you only need it as "credits" an IntegerField would probably be better.

Comment: Okay! I think I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, can you subtract the `DurationField` from another time instance?

Comment: If I should use the `DurationField` I want my `DurationField` to lessen as the use consumes their credits.

Comment: A `DurationField` will give you a `timedelta` python object and a `TimeField` will give you a time object. It is not possible to subtract a `timedelta` from a `time` because it's not clear what should happen, when it goes beyond "midnight". However you can subtract timedeltass from datetime and date objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support a particular format for your data like 24 hour miltiary style.  Convert the information to Text.  You are limited to Django data formats and your Sql platform data formats.  But you control the user interface and all formats can be achieved when you deal with your data in text format.

Comment: So instead of using TimeField in my models, I should use CharField instead?

Comment: You should store the data as Date / Time for validation purposes.  But modify your front end code on how it displays that date/time data.

Comment: Django is Python code.  Modify the Python code on how it displays.  Leave the database code doing Date/Time.  Python code for converting to a string is str(DateTimeVariable).  Django is a crutch so that you don't have to code.  It does many things for you.  Problem is when it does not do things the way you like it creates more work for you than just doing it in Python.

Comment: Right. But my `data.get("session_credits")` is not a datetime variable. It's an integer. How should I convert an integer to datetime in 24-hour time format?

Comment: If you data is an integer.  Where do you expect to locate Date/Time data?  Sometimes date/time data is stored as something like the number of seconds from 01/01/1971.  That may be the case.  You have to find out how your data is stored as an integer if that is in fact the date time you seek.